# Sortablejs works div list with {{#each... }} on inside, but not on outside of div list

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, sortablejs

I'm trying to use sortablejs in meteor to dynamically create lists with items that can be moved from list to list.

I installed it like this `meteor npm install sortablejs --save`

It is working on a `<div class="list-group">` with multiple draggable `<div class="list-group-item>`'s when the `{{#each...` is *inside* the list-group div, but it does not work if I use the `{{#each...` on the *outside* with the intention of programatically creating multiple list-group divs.

Here is example code of the `{{#each...` on the *inside* of the list-group div:

```
<div class="list-group" id="unassignedCensusTracts" style="cursor: move">
    {{#each censusTractsInTerritory "rec3UvlTOifMbsmnq"}}`

                    <div class="list-group-item">{{number}} ({{county}})
                        <BR> confirmed: {{confirmedQty}} |
                        unconfirmed: {{unconfirmedQty}}
                   </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Here is the non-working code with the `{{#each...` on the *outside* of the list-group div:

```
{{#each territories}}
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">{{county}}{{number}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="list-group" id="censusTractsInTerritory{{@index}}" style="cursor: move">
                    {{#each censusTractsInTerritory _id}}
                        <div class="list-group-item">{{number}} | #{{qty}}</div>
                    {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">confirmed: {{confirmedQty}} | total: {{contactsQty}}</div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Here is the template...onRendered function:

```
Template.makeTerritories.onRendered(function () {
    console.log(this)
    // debugger
    Sortable.create(document.getElementById('unassignedCensusTracts'),
        {
            group: {
                pull: true,
                put: true,
                name: 'unassignedCensusTracts'
            },
            sort: false,
            ghostClass: 'ghost'
        }
    )
    // debugger
    Sortable.create(document.getElementById('censusTractsInTerritory0'),
        {
            group: {
                pull: true,
                put: true,
                name: 'censusTractsInTerritory0'
            },
            sort: false,
            ghostClass: 'ghost',
        }
    )
    debugger
})
```

Note that the browser doesn't pause on the debugger, so I guess the second Sortable.create is failing. The error in the console is:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: meteor.js?hash=e3f53db…:932
undefined
```

Comment: If you want the browser to stop on your `debugger` statements then you have to remove the `//`

Comment: True. I only wanted the third non-commented-out debugger statement to pause

Comment: What html actually gets rendered before the error?

Comment: That's hard to figure out since it won't pause on the debugger. Any ideas how I can find out the answer to your question?

Comment: Is your subscription to the `territories` collection `.ready()` when this template is rendered? If not it will fail because `{{#each territories}}` will be an empty set. The template will render with nothing in it the first time. I suggest `if ( document.getElementById('censusTractsInTerritory0') ) Sortable.create( ...`

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I'm going to need to get all the elements of a certain class and Sortable.create each one. How am I going to `if (all of the divs.myclass are ready)`?

Comment: Make another template below `#each censusTractsInTerritory` and then do `Sortable.create()` in those templates' `onRendered` events instead of in the parent. You can also avoid dealing with `{{@index}}` by using `this._id` as your div id.